# php - show the first 3 items from an multi-dim array based on dates

Tags: php, arrays, date, multidimensional-array

so here is what I'm trying to do. I have structured a list of locations and dates in an multi-dim array. and I want to show the next 3 upcoming dates in the output based on date and location. Also I need to show only one date per location at any given moment so basically the closest date from location 1, 2 and 3 and so on, and every time one of them is passed I want to replace it with the next closest one. I might need to add more location later on but I still need to show the first 3 upcoming dates on the output. Should I structure my array differently?

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

```
$event_dates = array(
    'location-1' => array(
        'date1' => array(
            'start' =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2017-7-30')),
            'end'   =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2017-8-3')),
        ),

        'date2' => array(
            'start' =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2018-2-18')),
            'end'   =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2018-2-23')),
        ), 
        'date3' => array(
            'start' =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2018-7-29')),
            'end'   =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2018-8-2')),
        ), 
        'date4' => array(
            'start' =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2019-1-27')),
            'end'   =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2019-1-31')),
        ),
        'date5' => array(
            'start' =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2019-7-28')),
            'end'   =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2019-8-12')),
        ), 
        'date6' => array(
            'start' =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2020-1-16')),
            'end'   =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2020-1-22')),
        )   
    ),

'location-2' => array(
        'date1' => array(
            'start' =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2017-7-30')),
            'end'   =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2017-8-13')),
        ),

        'date2' => array(
            'start' =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2018-1-8')),
            'end'   =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2018-2-11')),
        ), 
        'date3' => array(
            'start' =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2018-7-23')),
            'end'   =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2018-8-12')),
        ), 
        'date4' => array(
            'start' =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2019-1-17')),
            'end'   =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2019-1-23')),
        ),
        'date5' => array(
            'start' =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2020-6-16')),
            'end'   =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2020-6-22')),
        )
),

 'location-3' => array(
        'date1' => array(
            'start' =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2017-5-12')),
            'end'   =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2017-5-19')),
        ),

        'date2' => array(
            'start' =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2018-9-22')),
            'end'   =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2018-9-28')),
        ), 
        'date3' => array(
            'start' =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2018-3-12')),
            'end'   =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2018-3-20')),
        ), 
        'date4' => array(
            'start' =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2019-12-9')),
            'end'   =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2019-12-15')),
        ),
        'date5' => array(
            'start' =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2020-11-16')),
            'end'   =>  date('m-d-Y',strtotime('2020-11-20')),
        )
));
```

Comment: I love helping others with array questions.  Can you provide your latest/best coding attempt to self-solve?  Can you confirm that you desire two separate results: one result with 3 nearest upcoming dates for each location, and another result with 1 nearest upcoming date per location?  Are you including events that are currently underway? or only events that haven't yet started?  As for array keys, I would literally be naming `location-n` as a specific venue name, and `date-n` as the event name -- maybe you are already doing that.

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm so sorry for the long delay. and thank you so much for your patience. so as for the results I don't really need to display two separate results. I just want to show the 3 nearest upcoming dates but only 1 results per location. doe shat makes sense? and as I mentioned before I might have to add more locations later on. so right now I only have 3 locations but later I might add 2 or 3 more but still I only wants to show the next 3 nearest dates. Thanks

Comment: What happens if the current date falls after the start date and before the end date?  Do I list the event in progress, or shift to the next event which hasn't yet begun?

Comment: @mickmackusa if the current date is between start and end of and event, that date should be counted for ( as in progress ) so I need to show it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to the rescue!

Code ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bea43aae52183f1be617a47811782ea11407967d)):

```
$TZ=new DateTimeZone('UTC');  // make some sort of declaration on timezone
$today=new DateTime('NOW',$TZ);
$today->setTime(0,0,0);    

foreach($event_dates as $locname=>$datearray){
    foreach($datearray as $eventname=>$eventarray){  // I recommend changing 'date{n}' to an actual eventname in the array
        $end=DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y',$eventarray['end'],$TZ)->setTime(0,0,0);
        if($today<=$end){
            echo "$locname's $eventname";
            $start=DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y',$eventarray['start'],$TZ)->setTime(0,0,0);
            $days=abs($today->diff($start)->days);
            if($today==$start){
                echo " begins today!";
            }elseif($today==$end){
                echo " concludes today!";
            }elseif($today<$start){
                echo " starts in $days day",($days!=1?"s":"");
            }else{
                echo " is in progress for $days day",($days!=1?"s":"");
            }
            echo "\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
location-1's date1 starts in 114 days
location-2's date1 starts in 114 days
location-3's date1 starts in 35 days
```

In an attempt to offer the most robust code, I've elected to turn my method into a function that will allow the designation of how many event dates to display.  Also, I discovered that location-3 had one date out of order, so I've included a sort() to correct this.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/79dafc679e3f74b03e69fafbc5c7f3a15d4cb631))

```
// for this sample array, $count=6 is the same as $count=-1
function currentAndUpcomingEvents($array,$location,$count=-1){ // default to -1 which will show all
    $result=[];
    $x=0;
    $TZ=new DateTimeZone('UTC');  // make some sort of declaration on timezone
    $today=new DateTime('NOW',$TZ);
    $today->setTime(0,0,0);
    // test a specific date: $today=DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y','08-13-2017',$TZ)->setTime(0,0,0);

    foreach($array[$location] as $eventname=>$daterange){
        if($x==$count){break;}
        $end=DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y',$daterange['end'],$TZ)->setTime(0,0,0);
        if($today<=$end){
            $start=DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y',$daterange['start'],$TZ)->setTime(0,0,0);
            $days=abs($today->diff($start)->days);
            $result[$days]="$location's $eventname";  // using $days as keys will allow sorting
            if($today==$start){
                $result[$days].=" begins today!";
            }elseif($today==$end){
                $result[$days].=" concludes today!";
            }elseif($today<$start){
                $result[$days].=" starts in $days day".($days!=1?"s":"");
            }else{
                $result[$days].=" is in progress for $days day".($days!=1?"s":"");
            }
        }
        ++$x;
    }    
    ksort($result);  // location-3's date3 was originally out of order
    return $result;
}

foreach(array_keys($event_dates) as $location){
    echo implode("\n",currentAndUpcomingEvents($event_dates,$location,6));  // whole array, level1 key, events per location count
    echo "\n\n";
}
```

Output:

```
location-1's date1 starts in 114 days
location-1's date2 starts in 317 days
location-1's date3 starts in 478 days
location-1's date4 starts in 660 days
location-1's date5 starts in 842 days
location-1's date6 starts in 1014 days

location-2's date1 starts in 114 days
location-2's date2 starts in 276 days
location-2's date3 starts in 472 days
location-2's date4 starts in 650 days
location-2's date5 starts in 1166 days

location-3's date1 starts in 35 days
location-3's date3 starts in 339 days
location-3's date2 starts in 533 days
location-3's date4 starts in 976 days
location-3's date5 starts in 1319 days
```

Comment: @eimansepanta I hope that you find my two codes satisfying.  Unless you discover something that is not quite right, please award my answer the green tick as well as an upvote for being helpful (I spend some quality time on it for you).  In the future, always post your own coding attempt in your question because answerers are _really_ not mean to write new code for askers.

Comment: Wow! what can I say? This did exactly what I wanted. thank you so much sir for your time :)